# An error occurred (404) when calling the PutObject operation: Not Found

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I wanna upload files into the s3 cloud with this code:

```
session = boto3.session.Session()
s3_client = session.resource('s3',
                               endpoint_url=credentials.get('endpoint_url'),
                               aws_access_key_id=credentials.get('access_key'),
                               aws_secret_access_key=credentials.get('secret_key'),
                               )
bucket = s3_client.Bucket("test")
bucket.upload_file("req.txt", "req.txt")
```

and I get this error:

```
boto3.exceptions.S3UploadFailedError: Failed to upload req.txt to test/req.txt: An error occurred (404) when calling the PutObject operation: Not Found
```

also, I am using this code:

```
session = boto3.session.Session()
s3_client = session.client(service_name='s3',
                           endpoint_url=credentials.get('endpoint_url'),
                           aws_access_key_id=credentials.get('access_key'),
                           aws_secret_access_key=credentials.get('secret_key'),
                           )


def upload_file(filename, bucket_name, name_in_bucket):
    s3_client.upload_file(filename, bucket_name, name_in_bucket)


upload_file('req.txt', 'test_mmdaz', 'testfile.txt')
```

and I get the same error.
any idea:?

Comment: Does `req.txt` exist in your working directory when you run the code?

Comment: I think you need to put your access and secret key in your Session creation. Not when defining your s3 client. [See Session Doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html)

Comment: @jordanm
yes! of course.

Comment: @RobertoS I tried this and get same error!

Comment: What are you passing for `endpoint_url`?  You usually don't have to specify that.

Comment: Are the credentials you are using for the correct account the bucket is in?

Comment: @stdunbar because I am not using Amazon for s3. I am using the other s3 service.

Comment: @RobertoS Yes, my stupid fault was here. thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to @RobertoS comment, My fault is that the bucket: `test` isn't in my s3 cloud object service.